# What is the expected value of the expected of x conditional of y? $E(E(X|Y))$ and also if possible $E(X^2|Y)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, expected-value

What is the expected value of the expected of x conditional of y? $E(E(X|Y))$ and $E(E(X^2|Y))$?

I was doing this question. And got this result. But got stumped at the next question. Which asks me to find the expected value of the conditional probability.

[image]

> I guessed and computed it like this. Getting $E(E(X|Y)) = 2.020$

[image]

> I guessed and got $E(E(X^2|Y))= 4.840$

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could clean up a bit and remove these non-self explanatory Excel screen shots and replace them with two lines of computations each.

Comment: But sheb they explain my working out. I don't think it's better to include some form of evidence of effort and reasoning.

Comment: It's far easier to read a calculation in $\LaTeX$ than it is to read an Excel sheet.

Comment: The characterization in this question is not quite right: "$E[E[X^2|Y]]$" asks not for the expectation of a "conditional probability"; rather, it asks for the expectation of a *random variable* (namely, the variable $E[X^2|Y]$). There's nothing new in that: the calculation is carried out exactly as it would be with any random variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parentheses do not match, almost nowhere, this makes your question ambiguous. If you mean $E_Y(E_X(X|Y))$, then your answer is the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Basically $E_Y(E_X(g(X)|Y))=E(g(X))$

Comment: So it's just  E[E(X^2|Y)] = E(X^2) = 1*0.34 + 4*0.51+9*0.15? which is also = 4.841

And E[E(X|Y)] = E(X) = 1*0.34 + 2*0.51+3*0.15 which is also 2.020

Comment: Sheb? responds plox how's this?